# Setting up a user without a password

Tags: ubuntu, su, useradd

I'd like to be able to `su` to another user to run a script with reduced permissions. Unfortunately I have to type the password in every time, is there a way to create a user without needing the password prompt?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try `sudo`.

Add the following to your `sudoers` file (by running `visudo`):

```
%you ALL= (restricted) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

where `you` is your username and `restricted` is your reduced privilege user.

You can then run commands as `restricted` without supplying a password:

```
sudo -u restricted whoami
```

You can also limit what commands can be executed via sudo by replacing the `ALL` at the end of the line with the command line you want to allow. See `man sudoers` for more information.

Comment: Another advantage of sudo is that it logs all commands to syslogd

Answer (score 0):

You can su to **root**, and then when you su to another user, the password is not required.